# How do we define the order relation in $\mathbb{R}$ in the construction via Cauchy sequences?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, cauchy-sequences, number-systems

I am reading the article of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers) about the contruction of $\mathbb{R}$ via Cauchy sequences, but I don't understand why the order relation that appears in the article is well-defined. It says that for all $[(a_n)],[(b_n)]\in\mathbb{R}$ we have that $[(a_n)]\leq [(b_n)]$ if and only if there exists a natural $N$ such that $a_n\leq b_n$ for all $n\geq N$.

I want to prove that this relation is well-defined.

Let $[(a_n)]$,$[(b_n)]$,$[(c_n)]$ and $[(d_n)]$ be real numbers. Suppose that $[(a_n)]=[(c_n)]$,$[(b_n)]=[(d_n)]$ and $[(a_n)]\leq [(b_n)]$, and our aim is to show that $[(c_n)]\leq [(d_n)]$. However, if we considered $(a_n)=(d_n)=(-\frac{1}{n})$ and $(b_n)=(c_n)=(\frac{1}{n})$, the hypothesis of the statement would hold but the conclusion would fail.

I would thank if you told me where I'm wrong or what I should do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct - this is a mistake. The right definition of $[(a_n)]\le[(b_n)]$ is

> **for every $\epsilon>0$**, there is some $N$ such that for all $n>N$ we have $a_n\le b_n+\epsilon$.

(To avoid circularity issues, $\epsilon$ here should be rational. But this is a side point.)

In fact, though, the sort of counterexample you suggest ("two Cauchy sequences approaching the same number from different sides") is *not* the only way that the proposed definition is problematic. We can for example find two *increasing* Cauchy sequences which approach the same value but do not satisfy the proposed definition:

> Consider e.g. $$0,1.2, 1.21, 1.222,...$$ versus $$1, 1.1, 1.22, 1.221, ...$$ and note that they each converge to $1.22222...$.

Comment: Thanks!! I was very sad for not being able to prove that the relation was well-defined. Do you know some book which contains all the construction of the real numbers using Cauchy sequences?

Comment: @LordVader You can check out Analysis I from Terence Tao.

Comment: @user0102 thank you, I will check it out later.

Comment: Can you give me some hint to prove that this order relation is well-defined?

Comment: Why should it work when $\leq $ is replaced by $<$? We can take $a_n=1,b_n=1+(1/n)$ and yet these sequences generate the same real $1$.

Comment: I prefer the following. $[(a_n)] <[(b_n)] $ if there is exists an $\epsilon >0$ and a positive integer $N$ such that $b_n\geq a_n+\epsilon $ for all $n\geq N$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Wow that's embarrassing, thanks. Fixed!

Comment: +1 there, and just to clarify I have made similar mistakes on mathse.

Comment: Maybe someone should fix the Wikipedia page also.